# Duplicate dynamic Link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page displaying random bible quotes from which you can also search. The quotes on this page are displayed in dynamic link format, e.g. bible-query.php?id=200

On the search results page, I have put a link each at the bottom and top of the page to help the users get back to the random display page. These links are dynamic links. The only problem is, I can only get the top link to display the dynamic link, the bottom one just loads a page with no quotes.

What I want is to have the bottom and top 'Back' links display the same dynamic link location.

Here is the code I have for the search results:

```
<html>
<font face="arial">
<title>BQuotes: Random Bible Verses</title>
<?php
// db requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="username";
$db_password="password";
$db_name="name";
$db_tb_name="table";
$db_tb_atr_name="line";
$db_tb_atr_name2="book";
$db_tb_atr_name3="cap";
$db_tb_atr_name4="verse";

//do search task


mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 

$db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%' OR $db_tb_atr_name2 like '%".$query."%' 
OR $db_tb_atr_name3 like '%".$query."%' OR $db_tb_atr_name4 like '%".$query."%'");

echo "Search Results<ol>";

// new bible query section begins


define ('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define ('USERNAME', 'username');
define ('PASSWORD', 'password');
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'name');

$db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to   
MySQL.');

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

$query = "SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<center><a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center> ";

}

//mysql_free_result($result);
//mysql_close();

//bible query new section ends




while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
echo "<li>";

echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name2], 0,160)," ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name3], 0,160)," ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name4], 0,160)," ";

echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
echo "</li><hr/>";
}






echo "<center><a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center> ";

echo "</ol>";

//mysql_close();
?>

</font>
</html>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is fetching the row using mysql_fetch_array. On the first time it runs it retrieves a result and so the value of $row is set to an array and the conditional is "true" so the bit in the while loop runs. However, on the second run-through there is no second row and so $row is set to false and the while loop doesn't run. This means that after the while loop $row is an empty variable. When it gets to the second calling of that array it is empty. By removing the while loop the $row variable is only fetched once and the first row is returned. This is all you need.

Just change this bit:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<center><a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center> ";

}
```

to:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<center><a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center>";
```

and both parts should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this. No need for a while loop since you are limiting 1 row in your query. Also I changed the php mysql function that you should use.

```
$query = "SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<center><a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>Back</a></center> ";
```

Noticed I used **mysql_fetch_assoc**

Comment: sorry Pjack not enough rep yet :)